# How can I enlarge an image with little to no pixelation?

Tags: raster, pixelation

I have an image that I need to enlarge to 84" wide and 72" tall. How can I do this with as little to no pixelation? Is it possible to do this in Corel Photo-Paint X6?

[image]

Comment: How large and what PPI is the original? You may want to review this question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolutions-should

Comment: Is that the actual original source image that you plan to use? I ask because it has problems way worse than low resolution. It appears to have already been upsampled at least once, and suffers from pretty bad jpeg artifacts. Regardless of what you do to it, that particular image will not look good at the size you want to print it. It will be a blurry, spongy, pixelated mess I'm afraid. You need a better original.

Comment: Enlarging in multiples of two is your best bet. You'd effectively be making 1 px cover a 2x2 pixel area, but at least you have a crisp recalculation.

Comment: You should really avoid enlarging images as much as you can. It's always easier to make it smaller than bigger. To that end, I would suggest using full-size art (or bigger) whenever it is available. You will need to talk to your printer to determine what 'full-size art' means. In large format printing, I've heard of people getting away with as little as 50dpi images. That means you are able to start from a much smaller source than a 150-300dpi image.

Comment: One thing to learn about when you're starting out in graphic design is how licenses work. You can't just take any picture off of Google images and paste it up on a building.

[According to the stock image site](http://www.f1online.de/de/bild-details/2985018.html) who licenses the rights to this picture, you can license a 504 square foot version of this image for approximately 3140 EUR (exact pricing varies based on your requirements).

Answer (score 4):

You can't, at least practically speaking.

An image only has so many pixels. To enlarge the photo, you either need to make the individual pixels bigger (it will be noticeably pixelated) or you need to make up extra pixels in between (it will typically be noticeably blurry).

For slight enlarging, the latter is usually acceptable--especially with some careful application of unsharp mask filters and the like.

That said, there is software that claims to be able to make up the extra pixels with smarter algorithms that supposedly reduce the blurriness. Typically done with fractals. I haven't used any of them. There are plenty of options. A quick google search returns many of them, this being but one example: http://www.imaging-resource.com/SOFT/GF/GF.HTM

Beyond that, sometimes you don't need to enlarge the image via software. Large format printing is typically not viewed close up. It's typically viewed from a distance. In that case, you may not need any extra pixels. Yes it will look pixelated if you stand 2' away, but from 20' it may look just fine.