# How can I wrap an existing design around a circular path in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, text, path, text-wrap

I am without my Senior Designer and facing a deadline that approaches before she returns. I've had a request from a printer creating tins for my company, to format our AI files to meet very specific requirements, ones none of us have encountered before.

What we usually send our printers is artwork files like this:

[image: Bottom of tin label]

[image: Side of tin label]

But what the printer is requesting:

[image: Dieline]

Putting aside the fact I'm not familiar with this method of printing, they are insisting they can not use the already formatted files to print with, and that we need to model our artwork off of their die line template.

Is there a method I can use to warp or wrap the existing design around a circular path without ruining the text? If it was just a single line it would be simple but it's an entire label design.

Comment: Are you talking about full artwork or just type?

Comment: The label is full artwork (text, logo and a large, simple graphic).

Comment: Ouch... that's a painful thing to be dropped in the deep end of! There are some tricks you might be able to use for warping artwork to fit curved templates on this question: [How do I map Illustrator artwork on a sphere?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/29212/3327) - different shape but you might be able to apply the same principle

Comment: Huh? The label on a can is a rectangle that they just wrap around the cylinder. I don't understand what your sketch of their request means for the "Side of Tin label". Voting to close as unclear, happy to retract it if you (or someone else) clarifies.

Comment: Hi Imogen, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for , but try it first.

1. First Group the Art,
2. Go to **Warp** under **Effects**,
3. Select **Arc**,
4. Slide **Bend** to ***100%***, make sure **Horizontal** is selected.
5. Slide **Vertical** to the left to ***-100%***
   See
   if thats gives you what you want.

Comment: Or  if its not exactly what you want, Try Grouping the art without the text, then curve the type separately.