# My printer is asking me for a huge jpeg that makes AI run out of memory. How do I fix that?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, jpg, file-size, file-format

I require a `10ft x 10ft` banner. My printer asked HI-resolution .`jpeg` file in actual size (1:1), but when I make the `.jpeg` file, pop up show I get an error of insufficient memory.

How much memory is required to make a hi-resolution (300 dpi) `.jpeg` file of `120 x 120` illustration

---

I read the answer, but not satisfied.

I make the design in `10in x 10in` & and apply gaussian blur and a lot of other effects and send file to vendor. When he increased the file in actual size (`10ft x 10` ) the original design has changed. So he asked for the `.jpeg` in 300dpi (`10ft x 10ft`) actual size. The design is for branding a store (digital print + pasting on sun board).

My system is I5 with 4gb ram.

Comment: Your printer specifically told you to provide a 120x120 inch 300ppi jpg file? [**See Here**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolutions-should) One workaround may be to **open** the AI file in Photoshop and save a JPG.

Comment: Seriously...? Actual size high re JPEG for a banner?

Comment: That's a 13 megapixel file. That's crazy.

Comment: well the raw pixels of that file will eat nearly all of the 4 Gigabytes doesent leave much space to work with. So expect it to be slow. So changing over to photoshop may be in order then atleast your not using more memory.

Comment: Try sending him a high quality PDF. He is most likely having issues with the Rasterized effects you are using.

Answer (score 7):

My first, second and third answers to this question would be "Find a different printer, because the one you have is incompetent." There is no grande format equipment made that *requires* jpeg as input. Typical spec, this one from the Fuji website:

> **Formats**
>
> All popular desktop formats including PostScript 3, EPS, TIFF, PDF, both RGB and CMYK color spaces.

If you're stuck with this printer, ask him to be a little bit brave and try a PDF instead. Get him to experiment with a small PDF first. When he finds that works, he can tackle the big one. Many grande format shops are small operations with little technical understanding of the technology, but I've not come across one that didn't know how to handle a PDF.

If, in the last resort, you *have* to use jpeg, create it at 75 ppi, not 300. No 10 foot banner is viewed from 16 inches away, which is where it would have to be to justify 300 ppi artwork.

If even *that* isn't accepted, create a 120x120, 300ppi RGB document in Photoshop and place the .AI file, rasterize it, flatten, and output as a jpeg. Be prepared to wait while Photoshop works, because a huge image like that takes a long time to process.

Comment: Agree with the Alan's first 3 answers. A jpg that size is ridiculous.

Comment: Really? TIFF of such size even more ridiculous. So printers use CMYK JPG. It is quite common here as well.

Comment: @Vnovak Nothing wrong with a CMYK jpeg in principle if it's not too compressed and there's no vector information in the file, but a 120-inch grande format banner at *300 ppi* is ridiculous, no matter what the input file type is.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the answer was done. Personally, I think more interesting how to solve a problem instead his many memory you need ) You can open Preferences - Performance and increase Memory Usage, as well as assign Scratch Disk to your drive with most of free space. Let me know if you still have an issue.

Comment: looks like not useful ))) can't help without any feedback.. anyway, never had issues with  files up to 40,000 x 40,000px.