# Print Shop telling me file size is too big?

Tags: file-size, print-production, prepress

I work for a company that needed a 44x10ft banner to be printed through a print shop that was local. As "conscientious" as I was about file size. (using vectors, flattening images and going down to 1/4 scale at 300res) my file size is 526mb. After sending it to the rep at the print shop, he is telling me that he needs it UNDER 100mb for him to be able to print it. I spent hours trying to compress the file down to size but to no avail. I am beginning to question whether that is even possible for a banner that size with at 75resolution full scale? If anyone could please let me know if there is some way I can make this happen it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Find a better print shop.... and check this.....http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolutions-should

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot get to under 100mb even after using all the possible "print" compression features from InDesign (which is the software I assumed you're using, if not please specify), I would look for another print shop.

Obviously their requirements would force you to produce a low-quality product, it might be ok for them to force their customers to do so, but you're free to tell them you will not deal with them with such requirements.