# Exporting your logo

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

When exporting your logo in illustrator what is the best dpi for high resolution to be used for big banners?

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. As it stands, we cannot satisfyingly answer your question – only your printer is able to do that.

Comment: If it's an Illustrator file, Id assume it is vector and if constructed properly would be resolution independent. Meaning there would be no resolution to worry about and you wouldn't "export" anything, you'd save as .ai or .pdf and provide that. It would scale without issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need to print an image a certain size. What dimensions and resolutions should I use?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolutions-should)

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid your question is full of contradictions.

> When exporting your logo in illustrator

You don't need to export a logo made in ilustrator. The logo should be in vectors, so leave that way.

> what is the best dpi for high resolution

The "normal" resolution for printed media (magazines, flyers) is 300 ppi. High resolution would be more than that.

> to be used for big banners?

Big banners don't use High resolution, but low resolution, depending on how big and how far the banner would be. However this applies to photographs, not in logos. That is why the logo stays in vectors in all the process.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use image,  highest dpi you can find. If you have vector smallest/whatever you can find.

Comment: Please motivate your answer. Why is this the right answer to the question? Thanks!