# How to decide output printing quality and material for an image?

Tags: print-design, pdf

Ths is my first question on this site.

I need help, I have modified version of this attached sample photo from the movie promesthus.

[image: Image I want to print]

I want to print it and put it as a wallpaper on my room wall. I'm undecided about

1. Size for printing w.r.t dimension too large size selection may explode pixel unevenly.
2. Quality panaflex or glossy etc. Seeing the attach refer pic is there any recommendation on which it should be printed as?

I'm asking such because this is a costly affair and I want to do right the first time.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Leaving some legal issues regarding the use of images behind, with that size of image you will get a decent print the size of a business card.

Comment: would that not be too small? the card.

Comment: For a wall, yes. I'll post an answer in some mins to give you an idea.

Comment: No real legal issues for printing art to stick on your own wall. As for printing it as wallpaper, you can, and it likely will look fine from the other side of the room. This question will help with that: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolutions-should