# What scale to use for an extra large window graphic?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, export, windows, scale

The print shop I work at just purchased a over size printer, HP Latex 360 that uses Onyx Thrive. We have a client looking for a large scale window graphic to cover the front of their car dealership.

My problem is how to create the file the correct size or correct scale.

They have two rows of windows, sizes as followed:
17 windows that are 41.25 in wide x 111 in tall
17 windows above those that are 41.25 x 41. 
One window that is 46 in x 111
One window above that is 46 in x 41 in.

If my math is correct, my finished art size should be 747.25 x 152.

As this is my first project of this scale, should these be created window by window, as a whole, or in sections?

Comment: related and possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolutions-should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each window that is a different size would need to be a new document or artboard.

Each graphic that is the same size but different artwork would be a new page or artboard.

*If multiple windows are the same size and using the same graphic then you don't need to create multiple pages/artboards of the same graphics.

**But**

If the graphics are going to flow from one window to another, then I would create the graphics in 1 document in a vector editing program using multiple artboards. I would create the graphics at 10%, 25% or 50% of full scale and measure the distance from window to window that corresponds to the artboard distances from each other.

So If there is a 10" gap between 2 windows and I am working at 50% scale. I would place my artboards 5" away from each other. I am just assuming the height from the window to the ground is the same.

---

*Some clients prefer to send me every single possible graphic even though some of the graphics are the same. That way I would be printing 1 of each graphic instead of following a sheet saying this graphic is printed x amount of times.

Answer (score 0):

Since each window is diffrent i would suggest creating an artboard or image for each and if your measurements are correct you will be fine. 150 DPI would work well (this is what i use for large printed banners but could be wrong). Note:I am responding from a photoshop perspective.