# Saving large PSD as JPG

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, file-format, jpg

I have a 180cm × 900cm document in 300dpi RGB 8-bit and I want to save it as a JPG, but when I try to "Save As", the only available choices are PSB, RAW and TIFF, why?

I need it for overseas printing and to be sent online.

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Offtopic: you really, really, really do not need that file size. No way.

Comment: [Read this](http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/articles/a-handy-guide-to-image-resolutions-in-print-design).

Answer (score 4):

The JPG format has a pixel size limit of 65,535 x 65,535 pixels. Photoshop however limits JPGs and most formats to 30,000 x 30,000 pixels.

For any images larger than 30,000 x 30,000 pixels you are stuck with the PSB, RAW or TIFF formats, there's no way around that.

From [**Photoshop Help / Saving Images**](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/saving-images.html):

> Photoshop supports documents up to 300,000 pixels in either dimension and offers three file formats for saving documents with images having more than 30,000 pixels in either dimension. Keep in mind that most other applications, including versions of Photoshop earlier than Photoshop CS, cannot handle files larger than 2 GB or images exceeding 30,000 pixels in either dimension.

A 180cm x 900cm image at 300PPI is **21,260 x 106,299 pixels**. Which is way too big to save as a JPG and I suspect bigger than you need.

For more realistic printing dimensions, read through this related Q&A:
 **[I need to print an image at a certain size. What dimensions and resolution should I use?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolutions-should)**

If you really need a JPG at that size and resolution you will need to break the image in to smaller sections, but I suspect you can probably work at a lower resolution.

Comment: Hmm never knew the JPG limit was that. I can't imagine it's a coincidence that 65,535 is the 26-bit limit. Wonder why

Comment: The field that stores the number of pixels is 2 bytes long (i.e 16 bits) and a 16 bit unsigned integer has a range of 65,535 :)

Comment: how exactly do you break the image into smaller pieces when most applications can't deal with that size?

Answer (score 0):

With 300 dpi the file is too large to produce a jpg image but you can produce a png file out of it. Otherwise you can decrease the resolution into 72 dpi and save as jpg .

For more info visit
https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/file-formats.html

Comment: However, it depends on the actual function of the finished image - *you* can't just reduce the resolution because you think it's appropriate; that's the OP's choice.

Answer (score 0):

What will be the final print size? And how will you be sending them the image? I assume FTP, because there will probably be size restrictions for emailing it.

Tiff is probably the best output format. Or else pdf. Or if the final print size will be small, you could probably get away with a smaller jpg.

Answer (score 0):

great advice, thanks. I managed to get a billboard down which was designed at 50% @ 300dpi to save as a .TIFF by merging layers before flattening

You can always make the design size at 1/3 of the final size but at 300dpi for digital print - it will definitely then save as a JPG

Answer (score -1):

Even you asked for a .jpeg, i can assure you that .tif will do all the things way better - even Facebook best practices encourage .tif upload for high quality images.
From that size *(180cm × 900cm)* i can tell that you need it for print and DTP work. Normally, print factories will ask you for a .pdf to keep the color profile intact and the text as a vector but when that is not possible, .tif is the alternative.
You also have the advantage of saving the .tif with layers for future modifications at the print factory or without them for fast trade.
[Check this out](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10895/should-i-use-jpg-or-tiff-for-high-quality-prints)

Comment: Even when i tryed to save it as .Tif, photoshop said that the .tif file exeed 4gb so i can't.

Comment: But this is an irrelevant argument.  Both TIFF and JPEG have specific audiences.  TIFF is also considerably larger, file size wise, than JPEG.  As for the actual image size, this must be some kind of poster or banner. The OP can most likely get away with a resolution of 120DPI or less, depending on the situation of the finished product.

Comment: Try to lower DPI as @Paul said very wisely.  
An alternative is to manage you layers more effective - i'm just guessing here. In the past I've narrowed a 2.2GB _(at open)_ .psd to a 600MB one - the trick is to combine all levels adjustment layers (an example) to a single one, transform groups of layers in one smart object, and so on.  
As a last resort you can print directly from the .psd or you can marge the whole .psd to one single layer _(CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+E)_ then duplicate it to "new" - but in the last example it would be wise to keep it at 300DPI to be sure it wont be damaged to much.