# how create big vinyl banner 18" wide by 360" high

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vinyl

Help me please I need to create banner 18" wide by 360" high. Illustartor can create max 227,54 in.
Its my firs so big banner. Help me please.

Here GUIDELINES:
18" wide by 360" high. Keep artwork text at least 1" away from the left and right edges, and 10" away from the top and the bottom.

Comment: You create the design at a smaller scale. You can ask the printer how they would like to receive the graphics but it is common to design large graphics at 10%, 25% or 50% of the final size.

Comment: Another good read: [I need to print an image a certain size. What dimensions and resolutions should I use?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolutions-should)

Answer (score 0):

Most wide format printers would prefer artwork at a smaller scale. Perhaps check what scale your printer would like, otherwise 25% or 50% is common. Be sure to consider the scalability of your artwork though——i.e. vector graphics will have no problem scaling up, but photos or logos in pixels will. So I suggest if you make your banner 50% scale, make sure your images are twice the resolution they need to be.