# I can't Save Illustrator file as PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf

So I'm designing a 219" x 100" wall banner in Illustrator. Trying to save it as a PDF and keep getting an error box - "The dimensions of this page are out-of-range"

I have no crop marks or tools going... Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is rarely need to work at 100% scale when working in large format, for exactly this reason. Large format print work is generally printed at a *much* lower resolution so you can work at scale (i.e. lower size / higher resolution).

For example, 20" × 10" at 300 PPI is exactly the same as 200" × 100" at 30 PPI.

As always, talk to your printer (the person, not the machine) and find out what resolution artwork you need (if you're working entirely in vector then it doesn't really matter) and work at a more reasonable scale. You can find more relevant info here:

- [I need to print an image at a certain size. What dimensions and resolution should I use?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/26354/52050)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to save it as something too big for the PDF export capacity of Illustrator.

Try scaling down the image to a size that's (lots) smaller, and exporting that.

Since most of your artwork seems to be vector based, this should be fine. You might get some banding in the gradients, though.

Answer (score 1):

**Found a fix** that should be suitable for this. I was working on 211.2" x 60" (17.6' x 5'). I also, received "The dimensions for this page are out of rage" when trying to save as PDF for print. It is true that the adobe illustrator export capacity is 200 inches. I tested this by working with a blank canvas set to 198" and 200" and 201". Cheers to 198" working. But this does not resolve the issue because who really wants to scale down any of their art.  What worked for me was simple. With my illustrator file closed I right clicked opened with Adobe Acrobat Professional CC 2017. Then, File save as PDF from within Adobe Acrobat Pro. Reopened the standalone PDF of my 17ft billboard and all the artwork was intact. Zoomed in on vector text and shapes 600% zoom with crisp clear lines.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across the same problem, but after scrolling through my many artboards I discovered a microscopic artboard had been created inadvertently and that's what was causing the issue.  Once deleted I could export to pdf.  Just in case the solutions above don't work, it's worthwhile checking to ensure you don't have an artboard that you didn't mean to create.

Answer (score 0):

I have had that problem in the past as well. From a production standpoint, I would recommend scaling down 30-70% and working on that scale, exporting it, and sizing up at a lower resolution on Photoshop when your artwork is ready for production. I have had experiences in which my Printers had very specific instructions for export and conversely I've had Printers who have been very vague about how they want artwork prepared.

To reduce the room for error I always do a little in-house print test when I am about ready for production. I print the banner at 100% on letter or tabloid (meaning I will only capture a small part of the banner) and tape it on the wall. I stand in real time however far away from the wall as I anticipate the final artwork will be viewed at and see if I like the product. This allows me to adjust my artwork even before I see a proof from my printers. I highly recommend this especially for newer designers who may not have a good grasp of what resolution works best at which scale.

Hope that helps,
Louise

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution. I had a teeny tiny artboard that was accidentally created with the artboard tool. It was just a few pixels wide. Once I found it and deleted it - all saving errors were resolved! Hope that helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good solution if you have Actobat.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBhbSz4Uhpw

Comment: Hi Shige, welcome to GDSE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

I have found that when that error comes up it is directly related to the size of the **Artboard**. If you go too close to the edges, width wise, it says that. So keep your artwork to the same size but **change your artboard size**, it will only affect what your preview looks like. Hope this helps!