# What Resolution Do I need for A Massive Company Sign in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resolution, print-production

I'm making a flat company sign for outside our building and the sizes are:

**Left Sign**: (Width) 8.0 Meters x 0.850M (Length)

**Right Sign**: (Width) 7.0 Meters x 0.850M (Length)

I have 2 questions.

1. What resolution would you suggest for a sign this big? I'm using Adobe Photoshop 7. The company that is printing the sign said "make it the biggest your computer can handle" i'm not sure what they mean by that. We run windows 7.
2. I convert the meters into mm or cm but it says it's too high. what should I do?

Comment: Marked as duplicate of http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolutions-should/26355#26355, also see http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be/2060#2060

Answer (score 0):

This kind of job is typically processed via Adobe Illustrator (AI), since that can scale up a couple of centimeters of artwork without any loss of quality and without worrying about the resolution. So if this is about creating a completely new artwork and you have AI available, i suggest you use AI.

If you are already reusing parts from other artwork previously made in Photoshop (PS) and/or only have PS to work with and/or your artwork needs to use raster images (photos, etc) your best bet is to take the print providers' advice and make it really big.

Try making it 50% smaller so instead of 8x0.85 make it 4x0.42 at 300 dpi. With artwork this big you assume people will not inspect these from close distance, so printing a 50% scaled down version is usual. You might want to re-confirm this with your printer however, just to make sure they agree.

Comment: Viewing distance is CRITICAL aspect of this. Think of a stadium with people holding cards to make a picture. You won't see the whole image from too close. From far away, huge pixels (cards) make a smooth picture. Content matters too. Printing smooth curved lines is different than reproducing a Monet. You might need higher resolution in the first case. Colors also matter -- how many plates are used has an impact on how fuzzy or crisp an image appears up close with large halftone screens. Hope that doesn't just confuse the issues.