# Can I use 72 dpi images in stand-up banner for print?

Tags: print-design, resolution

Will it be appropriate printed quality if use images at original size with resolution 72 dpi in banner 80 cm x 200 cm?

Comment: What sizes in pixels are the images you intend to use? What size do you want to have them on the banner? What resolution are you using to print the banner? There are too many unknowns here to give you a sensible answer.

Comment: @BillyKerr, images are 900x600 pixels, I would use them at this original size... but 72 ppi. 
Printer requires 150 ppi (minimum) for banner... it also concerns images that could be used?

Comment: @Olenia if they look fine when you put them on the banner, then it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Take the original ppi information and throw it for the window.

The original ppi information does not matter. The question is the original size of the image.

900 x 600 px... for a 80x200 cm print... now that is the problem.

You have a **totally wrong proportion**.

Regarding the resolution.

600 px across 200 cm are about 3 pixels per cm. That is 3 mm each pixel.

If you can live with that, go ahead. If the image is the only one you have, for example, is taken with an ultra sensitive gamma ray camera (with resolution limitations) and it is the only proof bigfoot was on your backyard, use it. If not, go and find another image.

But the real resolution needs are defined by the viewing distance and the usage intended.

Take a look: [I need to print an image at a certain size. What dimensions and resolution should I use?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-at-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolution-shoul)

---

Oh if you have a lot of tiny images, 900x600px at 72ppi at a final size of 32x21 cm yes, 72 ppi is fine.

Comment: I am sorry, but I meant **images at original size**, which will be composed on a 80x200cm banner...

Comment: Oh. I edited this. Then yes. 72 ppi is fine.