# Failing to export PDF from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, export

I have an artboard that is 565 x 28 cm
I am unable to export it as a PDF. Can someone guide me as to how to do this?
It is still within Canvas range, but bearly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to print an image at a certain size. What dimensions and resolution should I use?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-at-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolution-shoul)

Comment: Hi MAnnie, since Illustrator uses [vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics), which can be scaled at will, the size of your artwork is irrelevant and you do not need to design to a 1:1 scale. You can just as well design at 5.65 x 0.28 cm, as long as you tell your printer what the final dimensions need to be. See the linked question above for more info.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a banner or some other large format print item, you should contact your printer before doing this. Most likely you **don't** need to export a 1:1 sized PDF, but a scaled down version, half the size or even smaller. The printer should be able to give you precise specs for this.