# Is it possible to set the width in Adobe illustrator to 45m?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, print-design, print-production

It's for printing in a scaffold sheeting roll and client wants me to format it in three different sizes:

1. 3m x 45m – 2m Height Print
2. 3m x 45m – 1.8m Height Print
3. 2m x 45m – 1m Height Print

I'm not really sure how to go around with this. Can anyone help me or explain what they meant? They also asked me to download a different software just so I can set the width to 45m for printing.

Comment: Draw in scale and instruct your printer to scale it up. Although realistically you should be talking to the print company right about now.

Comment: No. The maximum artboard size in Illustrator is 577cm x 577cm. So you would need to work it at a smaller scale, then the printer can scale it up. If everything is vector then there should be no problem doing that. Speak to your printer about this. Aslo I've no idea what they mean by these dimensions. You'll need to ask your client.

Comment: @BillyKerr no thats not the maximum  you can lift the size when you create the document initially. BUT and this is a big but, you need to be aware that doing this will cause issues with precision. The maximum you can lift it to is 5779 cm or 57 meters. However your printer may not like that like at all.

Comment: @joojaa oh, ok. Didn't realise they'd added that new feature to 24.2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need to print an image at a certain size. What dimensions and resolution should I use?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-at-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolution-shoul)

Comment: There are many questions here about printing large size vector images, take a look around. TL/DR: you don't need to setup the Illustrator canvas 1:1 with the print size.

Comment: @Luciano no but if its possible to make the canvas 1:1 size then why not do it? I mean yeah if you need smethingg wider than 58 meters then sure.

Comment: Heaven knows what they meant – their measurements make no sense. If they want the three sizes to be 2m, 1.8m and 1m in height, respectively, then why on Earth would they give you the sizes as 3m, 3m and 2m? They might as well have just said 2x30m, 1.8x27m and 1x22.5m and be done with it, since those appear to be the sizes they actually want.

Answer (score 1):

As of [illustrator 24.2](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/larger-canvas-in-illustrator-24-2-100x-more-space/td-p/11243556) you can make up to 57.7955 m canvases. However, it is a trade off you are effectively cutting a two digits of precision of the file. However this is not so much of a problem since a double float has quite a lot of it to begin with.

Some restrictions apply, mainly for file formats that can get saved. One can also get into problems with using older versions of PDF viewers.

The trick is that you must specify a bigger size than than 577cm maximum when you first create your document. This triggers the extra large mode.